Same entities in two projects but different generated implementation by org.mapstruct

UserEntity
 @Entity
 @Data
 @Builder
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 public class UserEntity /*implements UserDetails*/{
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
     private long id;

     private String username;
     private String password;

     @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinTable(
             name = "users_roles",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                     name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
             inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                     name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
     private Collection<RoleEntity> roles;
  }


UserModel
 @Data
 @Builder
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 public class UserModel {
     private long id;
     private String username;
     private String password;
     //private Collection<RoleModel> roles;
     private List<String> roles;
 }



and I have written a mapper
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserModelToEntityMapper {

    UserEntity toEntity(UserModel userModel);

    UserModel toModel(UserEntity userEntity);

    List<UserModel> toModelList(List<UserEntity> userEntityList);

    default List<String> mapRoles(Collection<RoleEntity> roles) {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(RoleEntity::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

But the implementation in generated class if different in two project
I am focussing on one method toModel here
first project
@Override
public UserModel toModel(UserEntity userEntity) {
    if ( userEntity == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    UserModel userModel = new UserModel();

    return userModel;
}

Second project
@Override
public UserEntity toEntity(UserModel userModel) {
    if ( userModel == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    UserEntity.UserEntityBuilder userEntity = UserEntity.builder();

    userEntity.id( userModel.getId() );
    userEntity.username( userModel.getUsername() );
    userEntity.password( userModel.getPassword() );

    return userEntity.build();
}

I dont understand why the two different generated implementation when I have everything version and configuration same.
help and suggestion please.

You are not showing the toModel method in your second project. The first project seems to be wrong somehow. Can you upload a reproductible github or something of the first project?

@antoine.lange : the entities and the mapper is same in both projects , and the generated code is different as shared above. it worng , but I dont know why , I have cleaned the project , checked dependencies.

check pom.xml compile plugin config for both projects; maybe you missing lombok-mapstruct bridge in one project
